# Find the area between the given function , and two tangents off of the point (2,-2)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So here is a general graph of the first couple directions. 
[image: graph]

$T_1$ and $T_2$ are supposed to be the points where the tangent line intersects the parabola. The tangent lines and points where the tangent line intersect the parabola are not exact placements, just a visual aid.

I'm supposed to find the area of the yellow highlighted area. I understand how to find the area but I don't get how to find the equations of the tangent lines with the given point $(2,-2)$ to find where they intersect with $y = x^2$.

Comment: What is the equation of the tangent line to the point $(x_0,x_0^2)$? Note that this point lies on the parabola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another strategy:**

Consider a variable slope straight line passing through the point $(2,-2)$: $\;y+2=t(x-2)$ and form the equation for the abscissae  of the intersection points of the straight line with the parabola:
$$y=t(x-2)-2=x^2\iff x^2-tx+2(1+t)=0$$
The line is tangent to the parabola if and only if this equation has a *double root*, i.e. $\Delta=t^2-8(1-t)=0\iff t^2+8t-8=(t+4)^2-24=0\iff t=-4\pm2\sqrt 6$.

On the way, this shows there are two tangents to the parabola through $(2,-2)$.

The double root is equal to$\;x=\dfrac t2=-2\pm\sqrt6$.

Comment: Where does the $(1+t)$ come from?

Comment: From $-2t-2$  on the l.h.s. that went to the r.h.s.

Comment: Ah okay. That makes more sense now. The parenthesis threw me off for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: you need to find the points $(a,a^2)$ on the parabola such that the tangent line through that point also passes through $(2,-2)$.

Comment: So I use the point-slope form so get $a^2 -(-2) = 2a (a -2)$?

Comment: @England: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to find the tangent line from $(\alpha,\beta)$ to a function $f(x)$. You should be able to prove that the point $(u,f(u))$ where the line meets the function $f(x)$ satisfy $$f'(u)=\frac{f(u)-\beta}{u-\alpha}.$$